# Automatically add guest to new calendar event

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-calendar-api

This is the first Google Apps Script I have created, and I am having some trouble. I used ChatGPT to give me the code framework, which appears to be primarily correct; however, there is a problem right at the start of the script with it not capturing the event that triggered the script. Reading through the documentation hasn't revealed what is wrong, and most examples I can find are using a Google sheet as the starting point and creating calendar events, which isn't my scenario.

The "Event object is not defined" console error message is showing in the logs. The errors were observed after actual calendar event creation, not the run button. I have the trigger set to run when a calendar event is updated (created, updated, deleted).

Here is the code:

```
function addGuestToNewMeetings(e) {
  var calendarId = 'bob@companyA.com'; // Replace with your Google Calendar ID
  var guestEmail = 'bob@companyB.com';

  try {
    var event = e.calendarEvent;

    if (!event) {
      console.error('Event object is undefined.');
      return;
    }

    // Check if the event title contains "Systems Review Scheduled"
    var eventTitle = event.getTitle();
    if (eventTitle.indexOf('Systems Review Scheduled') !== -1) {
      // Check if the guest is not already added
      var guestList = event.getGuestList();
      if (guestList && guestList.indexOf(guestEmail) === -1) {
        event.addGuest(guestEmail);
        console.log('Guest added to the event:', guestEmail);
      } else {
        console.log('Guest already exists in the event:', guestEmail);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Event does not match the title:', eventTitle);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Comment: @Matt M, it could be that `e.calendarEvent` does not contain any data for the `event` variable. To narrow down this issue better, you can **console.log** the `event` variable to see its actual value.

Comment: To include a complete [mcve], add the details of how you set up the trigger and the steps you followed to fire the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are new to Google Apps Script and new to JavaScript, I suggest you avoid using ChatGPT without the guidance of a human programming couch or tutor that guides you through designing the prompts and overseeing your conversations with this tool, as it is prone to have [AI hallucinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence)).

As you can see on the first line of the function declaration, the letter `e` is inside parenthesis. This letter is a variable, also called a function parameter. A JavaScript function could have none, one or multiple parameters.

The JavaScript line that is writing the error is

```
console.error('Event object is undefined.');
```

Because the event object assigned to `e` doesn't have the property `calendarEvent`. ChatGPT has hallucinated that property.

Instead of starting at ChatGPT, start at https://developers.google.com/apps-script. Pay special attention to the part that explains that Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as a programming language and to the page that explains the events objects, more specifically the section about the Calendar Events event object. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#Google%20Calendar-events.

Comment: Originally posted in Web Applications SE. I made some slight corrections.

Answer (score 0):

A simple adding of a guest to a calendar event:

```
function onCalendarEventOpen(e) {
  addGuestToNewMeetings(e);
}

function addGuestToNewMeetings(e) {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(e.calendar.calendarId);
  const evt = cal.getEventById(e.calendar.id);
  var guestEmail = 'bob@companyB.com';
  evt.addGuest(guestEmail);   
}
```

manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Your Timezone",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "CalendarAddon",
      "logoUrl": "http://www.xxxxxxx.com/images/addons/fileicon.png",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#4285f4",
        "secondaryColor": "#ea4335"
      },
      "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
      ]
    },
    "calendar": {
      "currentEventAccess": "READ_WRITE",
      "eventOpenTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onCalendarEventOpen"
      },
      "eventUpdateTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onCalendarEventUpdate"
      },
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onCalendarHomePageOpen",
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects)

Comment: doesn't work. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'calendarId')
    at addGuestToNewMeetings(Code:6:54)
    at onCalendarEventOpen(Code:2:3)

Comment: It worked for me on my calendar. It looks like you may be trying to run this from the script editor and that won't work.  It needs to be executed by onCalendarEventOpen trigger from the CardService.  You need to build it into the user interface of the Calendar using the cardservice.